# ProGuard error with AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, proguard, runtimeexception

My Android app fails to export from Eclipse when ProGuard is enabled due to problems with the Amazon AWS SDK.

I'm using version 1.7.0 of the AWS SDK for Android (core & s3). The errors logged to the console are shown below.

I've followed the recommended ProGuard Config settings as provided by Amazon to no avail: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2OC71PFCTC63E/Using-ProGuard-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android

These are the jars in my project:

```
aws-android-sdk-1.7.0-core.jar
aws-android-sdk-1.7.0-s3.jar
```

Project.properties:

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../../../../../opt/ADT/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=../../../../../opt/ADT/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

My ProGuard Config is as follows:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose

# Otherwise return Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

# Preserve all fundamental application classes.
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

# Preserve Android support libraries` classes and interfaces
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }

# Preserve all Jackson library classes
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }

# Original
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}



#AWS
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler  { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.transform.sax.*     { public *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.**           { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.model.*Exception* { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.**                             { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.conn.scheme.**
```

Proguard output:

```
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleRequest
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AssumeRoleResult
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetSessionTokenRequest
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetSessionTokenResult
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.auth.STSSessionCredentials: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenService
[more com.amazonaws...]
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.HttpHost: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.HttpVersion: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AUTH: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthOption: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthSchemeRegistry: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthState: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.BasicUserPrincipal: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.auth.InvalidCredentialsException: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnPerRouteBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParamBean: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[more com.amazonaws.org.apache.http... can not find referenced org.apache.http.annotation...]
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase: can't find referenced class org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderElement: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderElementIterator: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[more com.amazonaws.org.apache.http...]
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.TimingInfo: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] Warning: there were 425 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-02-17 18:40:22 - Spream]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

And if i add

```
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.**
```

ProGuard works correctly but when I run the application, it closes immediately with this RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize the regions.
at com.amazonaws.g.c.b(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.g.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.g.c.a(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.g.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.gzanitti.spream.c.d(Unknown Source)
at com.gzanitti.spream.c.c(Unknown Source)
at com.gzanitti.spream.n.a(Unknown Source)
at com.gzanitti.spream.n.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
```

Any idea? I'm stuck on this problem for hours.

Comment: Yes, te solution was add: -keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; } and -dontwarn com.amazonaws.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with Proguard but with the missing regions config file. Make sure its available in the classpath of the final jar.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/src/awssdk_config_default.json

-k

Comment: Can u explain me how to add this config file

Comment: You will have to modify the pom.xml to ensure that the final jar contains the file. Have you verified if your apk has the json file?